# A cylinder is circumscribed about a sphere. If their volumes are denoted by $C$ and $S$, find $C$ as a function of $S$

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, volume, spheres

Here is the problem.

> A cylinder is circumscribed about a sphere. If their volumes are denoted by $C$ and $S$, find $C$ as a function of $S$

My (Amended) Attempt:

[Based on the correction suggested by herbSteinberg]

> Let $r$ be the radius of the sphere.

> Then the height of the cylinder is $2r$, and the radius of the base  is $r$. So the volume $C$ of the cylinder is given by
> $$
> C = \pi r^2 (2r) = 2 \pi r^3. \tag{1} 
> $$

> And, the volume $S$ of the sphere is given by
> $$
> S = \frac43 \pi r^3. \tag{2}
> $$

> From (2), we obtain
> $$
> r^3 = \frac{3}{4 \pi} S = \frac{ 3S }{4 \pi},
> $$
> and hence
> $$
> r = \sqrt[3]{ \frac{3S}{4 \pi} }. \tag{3}
> $$

> Finally, putting the value of $r$ from (3) into (1), we get
> $$
> C = 2 \pi \left( \sqrt[3]{ \frac{3S}{4 \pi} } \right)^3 = 2 \pi \left( \frac{3S}{4 \pi} \right) = \frac32 S.
> $$

Is my solution correct in each and every detail? Or, are there any errors of approach or answer?

Comment: The area of a circle is not $\pi(2r)^2$...

Comment: Radius of base is r not 2r.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "circumscribed" in this context. Normally I would expect the radius of the cylinder to be the same as that of the sphere.

Comment: @herbsteinberg thank you for correcting me. Is it legal as per Math SE community guidelines that I incorporate the correction you suggested directly into my solution?

Comment: I have never asked myself that question.  As long as editing is possible, just do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the radius of the cylinder is just $r$. Otherwise your work appears to be correct, but you've made things harder on yourself than necessary. Note that $r^3$ appears in both formulas, so once you have solved for $r^3 = \frac{3S}{4\pi}$, you can immediately use this expression in place of $r^3$ in the formula for $C$, going straight to the last equality.

In other words:

$$S = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 \Rightarrow r^3 = \frac{3S}{4\pi}$$
$$C = \pi r^2 \cdot (2r) = 2\pi r^3 = 2\pi\cdot\frac{3S}{4\pi}=\frac{3S}{2} $$

Answer (score -2):

The radius of the sphere should be equal to the radius of the cylinder face. Though you are correct about the height of the cylinder being twice the radius of the sphere.